# Don't run on Bluestacks or Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion, bluestacks

It is possible to detect if app is running on Bluestacks or Genymotion?

What information is reliable on BUILD?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

I don't want users to use my app on any emulators.

Comment: Maybe you can look android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER and android.os.Build.MODEL, for example it contains "GenyMotion" string on GenyMotion